# How to change value of table column (Status) from available to booked after [HttpPost] in mvc 4 entity framework code first?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```html
I want to book a property and display status of property from available to booked. How can I do this? Available classes are below. First I want to Show Booking table, after inserting data into Booking table, The next table I want to show is Payment table.If value of  PaymentType(Enum) is FullPayment then Property is booked and status of booked is stored in database across booked property and displayed in view. If PaymentType(Enum) is Installment then Installment table view is shown Installment process proceed...Please help me to implement this scenario. Must explain how Installment process continued. If there is something wrong with my models then suggest the correct model also.
Installment class contains InstallmentID,PaymentID, InstallmentAmount, ActualAmount, RemaninigAmount, NumOfInstallments, PaidInstallment, RemainingInstallment and InstallmentTitle
    [Table("Property")]
    public class Property
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
        public int StreetID { get; set; }
        public int SectorID { get; set; }
        public int PhaseID { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public string PropertyTitle { get; set; }

        public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
        public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
        public virtual Phase Phase { get; set; }

    }

    [Table("Payment")]
    public class Payment
    {
    
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PaymentID { get; set; }
        public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
        public int BookingID { get; set; }
        public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public long AccountNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
        public string PaymentTitle { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Installment> Installments { get; set; }
        public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }


    }
    
      [Table("Booking")]
    public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BookingID { get; set; }
        public int PropertyID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Member CNIC")]
        public string CNIC { get; set; }
        public string BookingTitle { get; set; }

       
        public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
      
    }
```

This is my Payment controller and from this controller I want to change the value of a Status column  from available to booked in property table

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PaymentID,PaymentType,BookingID,TotalAmount,BankName,AccountNumber,PaymentTitle,PaymentDate")] Payment payment)
{

        db.Payments.Add(payment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (payment.PaymentType == PaymentType.Installment)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Installment");
        }
        else
        {                             
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Property");

        }


    ViewBag.PaymentID = new SelectList(db.Payments, "PaymentID", "PaymentID", payment.PaymentID);
    ViewBag.BookingID = new SelectList(db.Payments, "BookingID", "BookingID", payment.BookingID);

    return View();
}
```

I tried this query but it's not working

```
var bc = db.Property.Where(a => a.Status == Status.Available);
```

Comment: Do you want to change status on create post??

Comment: Yes, If you Know about that please help me out

Comment: IS your property table has id of payment?

Comment: No payment table has no property id

Comment: I asked the property table has payment id ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `property` table has foreign key of paymentId.

After payment is created select the property with payment id

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PaymentID,PaymentType,BookingID,TotalAmount,BankName,AccountNumber,PaymentTitle,PaymentDate")] Payment payment)
{

    db.Payments.Add(payment);
    db.SaveChanges();


    var property = db.Property.Where(a=>a.PaymentID == payment.PaymentID).FirstOrDefault(); 
    // if you got multiple property for one payment use ToList() instead of FirstOrDefault()
    property.Status == "Available"; // change status here
    context.Entry(property).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges(); // save property
    // rest of your code


    if (payment.PaymentType == PaymentType.Installment)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Installment");
    }
    else
    {                             
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Property");

    }


    ViewBag.PaymentID = new SelectList(db.Payments, "PaymentID", "PaymentID", payment.PaymentID);
    ViewBag.BookingID = new SelectList(db.Payments, "BookingID", "BookingID", payment.BookingID);

    return View();
}
```